# How to exclude some files while using shelljs to move one folder to another

Tags: typescript, gulp, shelljs

I have below the structure repository:

```
src
  -common
        - asd.ts
        - filter.ts
  -checking
        -hi.json
  -third-party
        -src
            -common
                   -hello.ts
                   -two.ts  
                   -three.ts
```

here, i want move files from **third-party/src/common** to **src/common** but i have to exlcude **three.ts** file.

> I have treid like below bur it moves all files:

```js
gulp.task('common-update', function (done) {
  shelljs.cp('-rf', './third-party/angularSB/src/app/common/*', './src/app/common/');
  done();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`shelljs`'s `cp` function does not have the capability of excluding files when you ask it to copy based on directories or wildcards.

Options to get around this include:

- Use `cp` to copy over the collection as you have been and then use `rm` to delete the specific files you do not want in the destination.
- Gather a list of files and filter them according to your criteria, then use `cp` to copy over each file individually.
- Use a different library, such as [`copyfiles`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles), that does support some sort of exclude option.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried like this it works

```js
gulp.task('common-update', function (done) {
  var check = glob.sync('./third-party/src/common/*');
  for (var i = 0; i < check.length - 1; i++) {
    if (check[i].indexOf('three.ts') === -1) {
      shelljs.cp('-rf', check[i], './src/common/');
    }
  }
  done();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i am also looking for this long time ago.